# "Application- or object-defined error" in VBA code on my boss' computer but not on mine

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on a calculator in Excel VBA, and it all works nicely on my computer. All the systems and Office versions here in the office should in theory be identical, but for some reason it produces a 1004 (*"Application-defined or object-defined error"*) error when my boss tries to run the calculator on his machine.

I've tried to run the calculator on the same source data, but it completes successfully every time.

The run breaks at the `THEN` clause (`Then wsReport.Cells(iStartLine, 21).Formula = "=" & Cells(iStartLine, 20).Address & "/" & Cells(iStartLine, 12)`) of line two below:

```
dRTCBM = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("L" & iStartLine & ":L" & iEndLine))
If wsReport.Cells(iStartLine, 14).Value / dRTCBM < 1 Then wsReport.Cells(iStartLine, 21).Formula = "=" & Cells(iStartLine, 20).Address & "/" & Cells(iStartLine, 12).Address
    If wsReport.Cells(iStartLine, 14).Value / dRTCBM < 1 Then wsReport.Cells(iStartLine, 21).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"" USD/CBM"""
If wsReport.Cells(iStartLine, 14).Value / dRTCBM >= 1 Then wsReport.Cells(iStartLine, 21).Formula = "=" & Cells(iStartLine, 20).Address & "/" & Cells(iStartLine, 14).Address
    If wsReport.Cells(iStartLine, 14).Value / dRTCBM >= 1 Then wsReport.Cells(iStartLine, 21).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"" USD/MT"""
```

`dRTCBM` is a total cargo volume and evaluates correctly.

`iStartLine` and `iEndLine` are the first and last lines of the set of lines currently being reported.

`wsReport` is the worksheet used to store the report.

I can't replicate the problem on my system, and can't find anything in the code that might be causing it.

I've heard that going over a thousand or so lines in any one module could cause instability; this module tops out at around 1020. Could that be it?

Comment: Are you using any references that your boss doesn't?

Comment: How did you declare `wsReport`? Also, you qualified which sheet the formula should go in, you should probably do the same for the two `Cells()` used after (ie: `wsReport.Cells(iStartLine, 21).Formula = "=" & myWS.Cells(iStartLine, 20).Address & "/" & myWS.Cells(iStartLine, 12)) `

Comment: @Lance, no, it's all self-contained.

Comment: @BruceWayne - `wsReport` is used throughout the module and is declared in a separate sub which is called by each of the different subs rather than duplicating the addresses in each one. But I wonder if you might not be right on needing to qualify the cell refs - I left it out to avoid sheet references in the formula, but I'll give it a go and see if Excel is smart enough to strip them out. Cheers.

Comment: @BruceWayne Just tried it - even with the Cells clauses qualified it still breaks on that line. It's most irksome...

Comment: Have you tried debugging on his machine?

Comment: `iStartLine` being equal to 0 would trigger that error. Check the value of `iStartLine` on your boss's machine immediately before the line which causes the error (use a MsgBox or a breakpoint)

Comment: Yeah, I've got a watch on it. It initialises at 14 and increments one by one from there. Briefly tried debugging on his machine, but then he needed his desk back. ;-)